# loop and concatenate variable in workspace

Tags: matlab

I am trying to concatenate matrices station_1, station_2,.....station_10 from my matlab workspace and trying to concatenate all stations automatically using a loop and not calling them one by one like this
`cat(1,station_1,station_2,station_3,station_4... ,station_5,station_6,station_7,station_8... ,station_9,station_10` )

Any ideas?

the code below is what i was trying to improve

`for jj= 1 : 10 T= cat(1,eval(['station_', num2str(jj)])); MegaMat = cat(1,T) end`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading your code I think at the end of your loop you will have `T = station_10`.

If you want to concatenate all of them you would do

```matlab
T = []
for jj= 1:10 
  T = cat(1, T, eval(['station_', num2str(jj)])); 
end
MegaMat = T;
```

Using eval is not a good practice. Instead of creating `station_1` to `station_10` you could create a cell array

```
  station{1} = ...
  station{2} = ...
```

Then you could iterate like

```matlab
  T = []
  for jj = 1:length(station)
    T = cat(1, T, station{jj});
  end
```

If the number of arrays is big this will be slow due to memory reallocation and copy. In that case is more efficient to initialize T as a matrix of the final dimension and write slices.

#### Appendix:

There is an interesting notation trick pointed by @Cris Luengo in the comments, that is when you have a cell array station, use the notation `[station{:}]`, I have to admit, this notation is new to me. The only caveat is that if you set the items `station{i} = ...` then you will have the matrices concatenated horizontally rather than vertically.

The answer from @Mateo V, is also good, probably with leas overhead since it calls eval only once. That approach can be refined giving a one linear solution, and to be honest It felt not very unreadable.

```
MegaMat = eval(['cat(1', num2str(1:10, ', station_%d'), ')']);
```

Comment: thank you very much, i did try both options, and the second one seems to be the best ! thanks again

Comment: In the second case you can do `T = [station{:}];`. No loops, no preallocation.

Comment: @Malek: The 2nd one is the best not only in speed, but also in readability and maintainability. Avoid `eval` if you can, it has a lot of downsides.

Answer (score 2):

No need for loops:

```
str = num2str(1:10, 'station_%i,'); % returns string 'station_1, station_2, ..., station_10,'
str = str(1:end-1); % remove last comma
eval(['MegaMat = cat(1, ', str, ');'])
```